# How to show all annotations on mkmapview but with centering one in map

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, mkmapview, mkannotation

I'm showing all annotations in MKmapview by using "showAnnotations". The problem that i need to put one of those annotations in the center of the map.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: How do you choose one of those annotations?

Comment: @KosukeOgawa it's custom annotations so i can do that by id.

Comment: You will need to find the maximum and minimum latitude & longitude for your annotations and use that to create the region span for your map view and then set your selected annotation as the center

Comment: Have you tried  `mapView.SetCenterCoordinate(annotation.coordinate,true)`?